# best practice for sshfs via docker-compose to other computer but don't want to expose port publicly

Tags: docker, ssh, devops

I want to mount a volume in docker via sshfs to another computer that's ideally on my local network that my docker host is on. The problem is that it can't see the host if I try to ssh into via the usual 192.168.. ip. The other option I have is to expose the machines SSH port to the internet, but I know that is bad practice, so i'm wondering if there's any other way to do this? Can I connect via a VPN of some sort or can I make the docker volume reach my local network on my host?

Ideally i'm just looking for some guidance.

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  sshfs:
    driver: vieux/sshfs:latest
    driver_opts:
      sshcmd: "secretuser@192.168.0.114:/home"
      password: "secretpassword"
      allow_other: ""
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nx01
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - web
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend-vue
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/frontend/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './frontend:/frontend'
      - '/frontend/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/django/Dockerfile
    container_name: dx01
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
      - sshfs:/src/mount
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.django
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/postgres/Dockerfile
    container_name: px01
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: rs01
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:6379:6379"
```

Comment: Can you use sshfs first, then use docker-compose with the sshfs mount?

Comment: That's of course an option, but I would prefer to automate as much as possible using Docker.